# mod_rewrite and VirtualHosts: how to redirect 1 site, but keep the others?

Tags: centos, mod-rewrite, redirect, centos5, 301-redirect

I host 4 virtual hosts at a dedicated CentOS 5.6 server:

```
# rpm -qa|grep http
httpd-2.2.3-45.el5.centos.1
```

One of them is my Drupal 7.2 site and another was holding static texts and fotos belonging to my wife - here is the excerpt from httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 85.214.19.116:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/preferans.de
    ServerName preferans.de
    ServerAlias preferans.de *.preferans.de
    ErrorLog logs/preferans.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/preferans.de/access_log common
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <Directory "/var/www/html/preferans.de">
            RewriteEngine on

            # needed by Drupal 7 for "clean URLs"
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 85.214.19.116:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/larissa-farber.de
    ServerName larissa-farber.de
    ServerAlias larissa-farber.de *.larissa-farber.de
    ErrorLog logs/larissa-farber.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/larissa-farber.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now my wife has decided to move her files to Tumblr blog service.

As a quick measure I've put the following index.php into her dir:

```
# cat /var/www/html/larissa-farber.de/index.php
<?php
header('Location: http://larissa-farber.tumblr.com/');
?>
```

This works ok, but I'd rather use the mod_rewrite to do the redirect (that is - until I figure out how to transfer her web address to Tumblr completely, which should be possible too).

From reading the docs I understand, that I need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://larissa-farber.tumblr.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But where to put it and how to keep my other 3 virtual sites working?

Thank you!
Alex

(This is not a promotion of any of the sites above, I'm just too lazy to use fake addresses here and don't see a reason for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `mod_rewrite` for such simple redirects. Use [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive from `mod_alias`.

Place following into `VirtualHost` section with `ServerName larissa-farber.de`:

```
Redirect permanent / http://larissa-farber.tumblr.com/
```

Comment: This seems to work well, thank you, but: should I only replace the DocumentRoot line above? Or should I also get rid of the Server* and *Log lines in her VirtualHost section?

Comment: You should keep at least ServerName and ServerAlias records or Apache won't be able to select appropriate VirtualHost section.

Comment: That's what I've thought too. Do you think ErrorLog makes any sense to keep there?

Comment: I'd keep logs for a while just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualhost host directive for your drupal site already has a mod_rewrite section, just duplicate that structure in the virtualhost for your other site.  Alternatively you can place the mod_rewrite content in an .htaccess file in the web root of the specific virtual host you want to redirect.